# Could you provide an example of a SegWit transaction?

Tags: segregated-witness

I'm looking for a transaction ID of a non-coinbase SegWit transaction on the Bitcoin network. Could you show me one? Google doesn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a non-coinbase segwit transaction https://www.smartbit.com.au/tx/c586389e5e4b3acb9d6c8be1c19ae8ab2795397633176f5a6442a261bbdefc3a

Answer (score 4):

In [n.bitcoin.ninja](http://n.bitcoin.ninja/checktx) (weird name, but really useful page), you can find examples of every kind of SegWit transaction.

It is like a block explorer, so you will find additional Metadata and links between transactions.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0143.mediawiki

## Native P2WPKH:

```
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
```

## P2SH-P2WPKH:

```
01000000000101db6b1b20aa0fd7b23880be2ecbd4a98130974cf4748fb66092ac4d3ceb1a5477010000001716001479091972186c449eb1ded22b78e40d009bdf0089feffffff02b8b4eb0b000000001976a914a457b684d7f0d539a46a45bbc043f35b59d0d96388ac0008af2f000000001976a914fd270b1ee6abcaea97fea7ad0402e8bd8ad6d77c88ac02473044022047ac8e878352d3ebbde1c94ce3a10d057c24175747116f8288e5d794d12d482f0220217f36a485cae903c713331d877c1f64677e3622ad4010726870540656fe9dcb012103ad1d8e89212f0b92c74d23bb710c00662ad1470198ac48c43f7d6f93a2a2687392040000
```

Comment: also there is this EPIC Segwit thread, need to leave politics aside though...  see here: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1398994.0

Comment: Would also need txid and hash of the final signed transaction to compare with implementation. Can anyone confirm? I got the following for P2SH-P2WPKH sample: txid `ef48d9d0f595052e0f8cdcf825f7a5e50b6a388a81f206f3f4846e5ecd7a0c23`, hash `680f483b2bf6c5dcbf111e69e885ba248a41a5e92070cfb0afec3cfc49a9fabb`.